# permssion level for a particular folder in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

how to give read only permissions to a particular folder.
(Note: not for a whole library. only for a folder in the library

Answer (score 2):

Click the ellipsis (...) menu on the folder and select Shared With. In the modal that pops up select Advanced. On the resulting page, chose Stop Inheriting Permissions, then set your permissions as desired.

Comment: i didnt get you can u explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

Providing the visual screen shots of what @EricAlexander has described in his answer.

In order to set permissions to the folder in the library, we need to break the `Role Inheritance` of the folder and assign Unique Permissions

Following are the steps.

1. Goto the Document Library, click on the ellipsis of the folder you want read permissions. It will open a fly out. Again click on other ellipsis it has. Hover on Advanced. Finally click on `Shared With`

[image]

2. A pop up will open. Click on Advanced.

[image]

3. You will be redirected to the permissions management page. From the ribbon click on `Stop Inheriting Permissions` button.

[image]

4. Now you have ability to set read permissions to the folder.